# how to know when the user completes the textformfeild in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

how to know when the user completes the text field flutter,
for example, i need to apply a logic, When user complete the textformfeild,I tried oneditingCompleted method, but its not working, so please share the how do this one

Comment: "I tried oneditingCompleted method, but its not working" - share the code that you've tried

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you define "COMPLETE". What is "complete"? Is it when user press Enter? Is it when some text exists on the form? If I want to write Harry Potter in that form, what is the completion? Is it when Voldemort dies, or Severus Albus Potter gets on the train? Please provide more information.

In case of user press enter is defined as completion, use can use `onSubmit`. You can combine it with `validator` to ensure user types something there.

Answer (score 0):

You can detect when a user completes entering text in a `TextFormField` widget by utilizing the `onFieldSubmitted` property.

```
TextEditingController _textEditingController = TextEditingController();

    TextFormField(
      controller: _textEditingController,
      onFieldSubmitted: (value) {
        // Called when the user submits the form field
        print('User completed entering text: $value');
        // Perform any desired actions here
      },
    );
```